# Why do some methods have .prototype and others don't?

Tags: javascript

Question on `prototype`:
Why do some Array methods have `.prototype` and others don't?

[image: JavaScript Array method names screenshot]

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) states "`Array.prototype` represents the prototype for the `Array` constructor".

I am trying to reconcile this statement with the understanding that `prototype` is a property referring to the parent type, since that is how inheritance is achieved.

If the latter is true, then what is the parent type of `Array` who "owns" the methods like `map()` and `indexOf()`?

My main question is the one on the first line.

Comment: All functions do have a `.prototype` property.

Comment: @Bergi are you _sure_ about that ;)? (hint `.bind` and functions defined by the host environment)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Oops, you're right. Only the native *constructor functions* and any user-created function objects do have a `.prototype` property. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to reconcile this statement with the understanding that prototype is a property referring to the parent type, since that is how inheritance is achieved.

No. The prototypical relation to another object (from which properties are inherited) is done via an invisible link, sometimes denoted as `[[prototype]]`.

The actual, existing `.prototype` property on a constructor function is the object from which all instances that were constructed by that function will inherit.

So the prototype (inheritance) chain of an Array object looks like this:

```
                             null
                               ^
                               |
Object.prototype ---> {hasOwnProperty(), …} // all objects inherit these
                               ^
                               |
Array.prototype ----> {map(), indexOf(), …} // all arrays inherit these
                               ^
                               |
                      {length, 0, 1, 2, …} // an example array
                      // as if constructed by new Array(5) or [42, 7, 6]
```

---

> Why do some methods have .prototype and some don't?

The functions that are available on the `.prototype` will be inherited by all instances, you can call them directly on them if they were a method of them.

The functions that are placed directly on the constructor function, like `Array.isArray` or `Array.of`, are not instance-related and "static" so to say. You call them mostly with non-arrays as arguments.

Answer (score 5):

The methods that aren't on the prototype are like "class" methods in some other languages (*kind-of*; the similarity is superficial). Methods on the prototype are callable from the context of any array instance; methods directly on the constructor are not.

The "length" property is a property of every array instance; there's a "length" property on the constructor function too, but it's meaning is completely different — it tells you how many formal parameters are in the function (the Array function).

The "parent type" of Array, to the extent that such a thing makes sense in JavaScript, is "Object", but that doesn't have anything to do with the methods on the Array prototype.

Comment: I'd like to upvote this for being correct but the 'class' methods analogy is bothering me. Please consider expanding on what's happening. The main issue being that methods that are on the prototype are available to every array and usually have dynamic `this.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you help me out and let me know what exactly is bothering you?  I mean, it bothers me too, but I'm curious as to what exactly concerns you here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ah well I just added another sentence, coincidentally.

Answer (score 4):

The `Array.prototype.*` methods can be called on array instances, and appear to be 'method' of those instances, whereas the `Array.*` methods cannot (at least not directly), and instead must be called from the `Array` object itself.

For example:

```
[].concat([]) // calls Array.prototype.concat
Array.concat([]) // undefined

Array.isArray([]) // calls Array.isArray
[].isArray([]) // undefined
```

Comment: Well.. they _can_ be called on array instances (indirectly for example) - everything can be called on everything. It would just be pointless since they don't use the `this` value.